# jquery validation engine scroll false not working with validate

Tags: javascript, jquery

jquery validation engine scroll: false is working fine without 'validate' like below...
`jQuery('#form').validationEngine({scroll: false});`

But not working if I put like this.

`jQuery('#form').validationEngine('validate',{scroll: false});`

Actually i need **validationEngine** with 'validate' and 'no scroll'. any idea? 
Thanks.

Comment: Anyone faced the same issue plz let me know the solution?.

Comment: which library or framework are you using for jquery validation?

Answer (score 3):

You have to just add space after starting '{' and before ending '}' for  scroll: false.

```
$("#form-id").validationEngine('attach',{ scroll: false });
resp = jQuery("#form-id").validationEngine("validate",{ scroll: false });
```